# Accessing Microsoft Dynamics Web Api on premise from .net 4.8 and .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-365, .net-4.8

We are upgrading our CRM to **dynamics 365 on premise**, previously we were using crm 2011. While upgrading there is a business layer written in **.net 4.8** which was extensively fetching, updating, creating different entities using organization services. Now during the crm upgrade, we are analyzing the changes required on the business layer (whether we really need to upgrade this business layer to **.net core** or it will work fine with the **new 9.1 Web APis**).

I have found many SDKs and packages that supports **.net 4.x** but when i go to their documentations most of them are retired now.

So the option so far is only go with the web api using webclient if we want to go with .net **4.x(4.8)**

**Ask here is** has anyone faced the similar scenario are web apis are enough or do we really need to upgrade the business layer to .net core in order to get the maximum benefits. I have seen on the web people mentioning .net core sdk integration is more optimized and powerful but there is no real comparison as such that what capabilities are limited to **.net core sdk.**